# LNK1117: Syntax error in option "VERSION:1.0.0"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

i have a very curious problem, when i try to build with `Visual Studio 2013`.

Anyone can help me?
What i'm doing wrong?

**Original Message (German)**

```
1>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: npworpg, Konfiguration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1117: Syntaxfehler in Option "VERSION:1.0.0".
========== Erstellen: 0 erfolgreich, 1 fehlerhaft, 0 aktuell, 0 übersprungen ==========
```

**Translated**

```
1>------ Creating started: Project: npworpg, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1117: Syntaxerror in Option "VERSION:1.0.0".
========== Created: 0 success, 1 error, 0 current, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Can you show your link options ?

Comment: This error also happened to me, and it's not the same question as the one marked for dupe. Reopening.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've found the Problem!

On the Settings (**Project** > **Settings** > **Linker**) removing the "Version" entry.

Comment: It is not mandatory to remove the "Version" entry. Version number should only be limited to MAJOR.MINOR (e.g "1.0").