# Error LNK1117 in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt

I'm tring to compile a clone (git) project but I get an error:

```
:-1: error: LNK1117: syntax error in option 'VERSION:XXXX'
```

My platform is:

 1. QT 5.5.1 MSVC2013 32bit

 2. Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0 (x86)

 3. Desktop Qt 5.5.1 MSVC2013 32bit

I try to clean > qmake > rebuild but it doesn't helps.
(I know that the project is OK).

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LNK1117: Syntax error in option "VERSION:1.0.0"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471337/lnk1117-syntax-error-in-option-version1-0-0)

Comment: I work on QT Creator and i didn't find the linker setting to make the change he suggest.

Comment: can you share the project, assuming it's public/open source?

Comment: I am sorry but it is a private project that locatel on private gitlab, why this is matter?

Answer (score 2):

Based on MS documentation to linker command line options:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h88b7dc8.aspx

The only allowed format of version specified this way is:

/VERSION:major[.minor]